# Pencil tool in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Please can somebody tell me how do I get the forward slash line to show when I am using the pencil tool to signify it is joining onto the first anchor point of the first part of whatever I've drawn.

I'm new to Illustrator and it worked fine up until about a week ago. Since then the  forward slash will not appear and it just shows the star icon. I am going nuts trying to figure this out.

Comment: It *should* work. Try relaunching the app.

Answer (score 3):

Double click the Pencil Tool to bring up the Pencil Tool Options, and check the option "Keep selected". If this isn't selected, the path is immediately deselected after drawing it, and you can't then join a new line made with the Pencil tool.

[image]

Comment: Good lord, that worked, thank you so much. You don't know how many times I've asked the question in multiple guises on Google none of which came up with the answer. I am amazed and very grateful. God Bless you Sir

Comment: @IainRigby Well, I'm an atheist, but the sentiment is appreciated. LOL  Glad it worked for you.

Comment: This is the first time I've ever asked a question on-line in this format. Very liberating I must say. Thank you once again. I've got a cracking headache from trying to figure this out. I was about to give up when I stumbled on this site which I will definitley be using again. The lord works in mysterious ways, or not. Cheers.

Comment: @IainRigby Illustrator is sometimes horribly complicated, and often unintuitive. It gives me headaches too from time to time.  At least you're not alone. Let me welcome you to GDSE, and I hope you keep contributing and adding questions, and if possible, your own answers to help others too. We love to help when we can.